# call function with argument of a ember object with attr-bind

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have trouble understanding embers templates.

So I have this object that is assign to the indexRoute model:

```
App.Session = Ember.Object.extend({
  function_without_argument: function () {
    return 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Rounded%20World%20Flags/Spain%20Flag.png';
  }.property(),

  with_argmument: function (value){
    return 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Rounded%20World%20Flags/' + this.get(value) + '%20Flag.png';
  }.property()
});
```

calling `<img width="20" {{bind-attr src=function_without_argument}}>` works but not with an argument `<img width="20" {{bind-attr src="with_argmument answer.leader"}}>`.

Why?

I made a little codepen example: http://codepen.io/gurix/pen/zmdDh

Answer (score 0):

Computed property should not receive a parameter, instead use a property of the object.

Example,

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ghnsD

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.Session = Ember.Object.extend({
  targetFlag:null,
  function_without_argument: function () {
  return 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Rounded%20World%20Flags/Spain%20Flag.png';
  }.property(),

  answer_image: function (){
    return 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Flag/Rounded%20World%20Flags/' + this.get("answer.leader") + '%20Flag.png';
  }.property()
});


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() { 
    var session = App.Session.create();
    session.setProperties({ 
      token: 'abc',
      answer: {
        leader: 'Switzerland',
        looser: 'Argentina'
      }});
    return session;}
});
```

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

  without argument: <img {{bind-attr src=function_without_argument}}>

     {{answer.leader}} becomes the image ... 

    <img {{bind-attr src=answer_image}} >



</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this solves my problem not the slightest. So you say it's not possible to pass a parameter to a property of the object? So I have to create an object method like `leader_image` for each answer? Is there not a better way?

Comment: @MarkusGraf You shouldn't be passing a parameter at all. It doesn't make sense. melc is right. The image src should be a property of the `Session` object (either set during init or computed) and not a result of some template logic that passes a parameter.

Comment: ok I understand. So I guess i have to learn more about the philosophy of ember. I thought it would be an easy ways instead of writing methods for each image.